# How to disable serilog in Debug mode

Tags: c#, serilog

I am using `Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch` sink for logging as below in `Startup.cs`:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.Enrich.FromLogContext()
.Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
  .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(settings.ElasticSearchUrl))
  {
      ModifyConnectionSettings = conn =>
      {
          var httpConnection = new AwsHttpConnection(settings.Region
              , new StaticCredentialsProvider(new AwsCredentials
              {
                  AccessKey = settings.AccessKey,
                  SecretKey = settings.SecretKey,
              }));
          var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(settings.ElasticSearchUrl));
          var conf = new ConnectionConfiguration(pool, httpConnection);
          return conf;
      },
      ConnectionTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
      IndexFormat = "test-{0:yyyy.MM}"
  })
.CreateLogger();
```

When I am debugging my application in local using VS2017 those events are also getting logged too into Elasticsearch which I don't want.

How do I disable logging in Debug mode?

Comment: Wrap the initialisation in `#if DEBUG` … `#endif` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* find out whether a debugger is attached, but that's not very reliable (for example you could attach after the initialization of the logger).

```
if(Debugger.IsAttached)
```

Your best bet is probably conditional compilation and only initialize your logger when not in debug mode:

```
#if !DEBUG
   // initialize logger here
#endif
```

Please note that this checks for the DEBUG symbol, that is set through the "Debug" configuration, not whether you pressed <kbd>F5</kbd> or not.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at some way with Serilog options. Currently, this is the best solution for the problem.